# Why does QThread only print one of two thread calls?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qthread

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import time as t


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def _init_(self, mw):
    super(WorkerThread, self)._init_(mw)
    self.gameName = ""

def setGameName(self, currGameName):
    self.gameName = currGameName

def run(self):
    print self.gameName

class GG(object):
workerThread = WorkerThread()
def startThread(self,stringer):
    self.workerThread.setGameName(stringer)
    self.workerThread.start()

harro = GG()
harro.startThread("hello")
harro.startThread("hi")
t.sleep(60)
```

This only prints "hi" and not "hello". Why does it not print both? How would I change it so that it prints both?

Answer (score 4):

The second call to `startThread` cancels the first one. The thread don't have time to print "hello" that you call it again asking to print "hi".
You can call `QThread.wait()` just after `QThread.start()` to wait for the thread to finish.

A working example (also, with correct identation):

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def _init_(self, mw):
        super(WorkerThread, self)._init_(mw)
        self.gameName = ""

    def setGameName(self, currGameName):
        self.gameName = currGameName

    def run(self):
        print self.gameName

class GG(object):
     workerThread = WorkerThread()

     def startThread(self,stringer):
        self.workerThread.setGameName(stringer)
        self.workerThread.start()
        self.workerThread.wait()

harro = GG()
harro.startThread("hello")
harro.startThread("hi")
```

This example would freeze a user interface while a thread is running.
So for more complex tasks, you should use the signals and slots mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The example is quite small, in that the threads only do one thing (print a string), then exit. If you actually want to start two threads in parallel, you could modify your GG class to keep track of more than one thread object.

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def _init_(self, mw):
        super(WorkerThread, self)._init_(mw)
        self.gameName = ""

    def setGameName(self, currGameName):
        self.gameName = currGameName

    def run(self):
        print self.gameName

class GG(object):
     workerThreads = []

     def startThread(self,stringer):
        self.workerThreads.append(WorkerThread())
        self.workerThreads[-1].setGameName(stringer)
        self.workerThreads[-1].start()

harro = GG()
harro.startThread("hello")
harro.startThread("hi")
```